# issue importing UnityEngine.InputSystem. Error CS0246 type or namespace not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

despite having copied the code of a tutorial exactly, i'm being unable to run my code.

this is the video. the code can be seen in 11:37.

i installed unity 2 or 3 days ago, so i doubt it is an update issue (i saw someone on another thread saying this)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine;

public class controle : MonoBehaviour
{
private PlayerControls controls;  // the error points at this line, at whatever position the "PlayerControls" string is

private void Awake()
{
    controls = new PlayerControls();
    controls.Gameplay.Forward.performed += Forward;
}


void Forward()
{
    transform.position.z -= 1.1 * f;

}

void OnEnable()
{
    controls.Gameplay.Enable();
}

void OnDisable()
{
    controls.Gameplay.Disable();

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could possibly be because of a compiler order issue; your `controle` class might be compiled before `PlayerControls` exists and therefore it can't access it.
Here is [an example this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1274419/accessing-un-namespaced-class-from-unitystandardas.html?childToView=1274460#answer-1274460).

Check if you put your file in the Standard Assets folder, as files there are compiled before all the other class scripts.
You can read more [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Special_Folder_Names_in_your_Assets_Folder?_ga=2.81978897.682716731.1587799030-1405602278.1587799030).

Comment: but if i create inside the assets folder another one called Standard Assets and drop this file there, it's gonna be loaded before anyway, right? shouldn't i drop inside Standard ASsets the file with the PlayerControls class? which file would that be? @JentGent

Comment: @DavidSpira Files in the Standard Assets folder are compiled before basically everything in the scene. PlayerControls is an autogenerated class, IIRC, so you can't really access it and put it into a folder. You would have to move your file outside of the Standard Assets folder and into the Assets folder.

Comment: it is inside a scripts folder inside the assets folder. it was never inside a Standard Assets folder (which didn't even exist)

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: Hmm, then unfortunately I'm not sure of what your problem is. The question does not have enough context about the project; the code itself should work fine (I think), and it is probably something else about the project.

Comment: I have the same problem, just typing `using UnityEngine.InputSystem` generates the error : `The type or namespace name 'InputSystem' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' `. The Unity InputSystem package is installed but VS Code can't find it.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this? I'm looking for solutions for almost an hour now. Nothing works.